# css bottom margin applying to top

Tags: html, css

A zero-height div that has a top margin smaller than the bottom margin is getting positioned an amount equal to the bottom margin from the top of the page. Giving the div any height or putting any content in causes it to be positioned as expected. Why is this?

```
<div style="margin: 2px 0 50px;"></div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/atfu4waw/

(You will have to inspect element to see the div.)

Comment: use overflow: hidden; for div

Comment: While that works, I'd still like to know why. What's the rule or the logic behind this?

Comment: it's because of margin collaps
Margins between a floated box and any other box do not collapse (not even between a float and its in-flow children).

Margins of elements that establish new block formatting contexts (such as floats and elements with 'overflow' other than 'visible') do not collapse with their in-flow children.

Margins of inline-block boxes do not collapse (not even with their in-flow children).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because for empty boxes, the top and bottom margins collapse (the biggest one of them is used and the smaller one is ignored).

From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing):

> **Empty blocks**
>
> If there is no border, padding, inline content, height,
>   or min-height to separate a block's margin-top from its margin-bottom,
>   then its top and bottom margins collapse.

Collapsing margins are a feature of the [box formatting context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting) and the [rules for collapsing](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins) are sometimes complex.

---

Also if you're using Chrome dev tools to inspect your element you shouldn't really trust its representation of the margin as it is not rendered correctly (at least for my version it isn't). You can better check where the real margin is by adding content after the element:

```html
<div style="margin: 20px 0 50px;"></div>
aaaa
```

Comment: In the actual scenario that prompted this question, there were floated divs inside the zero-height one that ended up being positioned incorrectly. Content after the div does not reflect this and appears to be positioned correctly.

Comment: @someBSthisis I have no way of knowing what prompted the question if you don't say it in the question. What is described in the question's content is clear: an empty div with both top and bottom margins. From the collapsing margin rendering rule it results that the biggest of them will be used as the margin. That's how browser rendering is done. If you have more complex scenarios with floats and/or inline content things will change as there are more rules that affect rendering. If you want to understand more you can study the documentation I linked in the answer (It will take you some hours).